# How do I make contents inline preserving CSS of each element in asp page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I want to display child element's contents inline,should display in inline and preserving each elements css,text can be able to wrap if it not fits in one line.
 I want to display all contents in first span preserving style of each element.

code -

```
<h2>
    <span tabIndex="33" id="ctl00_MainContent_101">
        <div style="text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Segoe UI; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">
          <p style="margin: 0px; font-family: Microsoft Sans Serif;">
            <span style="font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold;">
              <span>What is your name? </span>
            </span>
            <span style="color: rgb(0, 112, 192); font-family: Arial; font-style: italic;">
              <span>Brief Introduction</span>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
  </span>
</h2>
```

The contents are now showing in two lines.
I have tried display:inline/inline-block/block so far
please help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format multiple lines of code by preceding each line with four spaces, rather than enclosing the whole thing in `\``. You also need to be more clear as to exactly what you're asking for, and maybe give us a mockup of what you mean.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: currently the contents of spans that are 'What is your name?' and 'Brief Introduction'  rendering in two lines i want them in one line with specified style of individual span.

Comment: Please edit your question to say as much, rather than responding in a comment.

Comment: You're `span` crazy. A div should not be contained within a span and you have more of them than you can shake a stick at. Learn your HTML DOM hierarchy and [validate your html](http://validator.w3.org/) (which will most probably help you learn).

Comment: However, copying and pasting your code directly into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94mkvtr0/) works as you're wanting it to. There must be a problem elsewhere.